# Highlight text in synch with audio file in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, audio

I am trying to develop an iPad app in which I want to highlight text in a text view. This will be in sync with audio file.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you want a good answer, you're going to have to write a good question. Right now, it's lacking a lot of detail that you need to add. How are you getting this audio file? What does it mean for the audio file and the highlighting to be in sync - does the audio file correspond to the text on the screen? How would you be determining what 'in sync' even means? Improving your question will increase the chances you'll get a good answer, or even an answer at all.

Comment: I've gone ahead and added tags to your question - the more relevant tags there are, the higher chances people who view those tags will see it. 'objective-c' isn't specific at all, but adding 'ios', 'ipad', and 'audio' better helps classifying the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked on a karaoke app and the way we did it was to read the lyrics and their timings from a midi file which corresponded to the audio, and use an AVAudioPlayer to play back audio, and wrote a custom widget that subclassed UILabel that display the text with the highlighting we wanted. Use the time values from the audio player directly rather than trying to keep a separate timer in sync or the timing could drift.

Comment: Hi, How can we do this with Arabic content

Comment: Hi Joeld, Please help me in this, I have read MIDI file and I am getting duration and note, now how do I read lyrics from MIDI file, do I need to convert something please help.